# ASP.net Retrieving data from database always failing with ajax

Tags: ado.net, asp.net-ajax

Got this jquery code am using to retrieve data from database through ADO.net:

```
$(document).ready(getBooks);

    function getBooks() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "main.aspx/getBooks",
            data: "{}",
            datatype: "json",
            contenttype: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                var TableContent = "<table>" +
                                    "<tr>" +
                                        "<td>ISBN</td>" +
                                        "<td>Book Title</td>" +
                                        "<td>Public Year</td>" +
                                        "<td>Category</td>" +
                                    "</tr>";
                for (var i = 0; i < data.d.length; i++) {
                    TableContent += "<tr>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].ISBN + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].BOOK_TITLE + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].PUBLICATION_YEAR + "</td>" +
                                            "<td>" + data.d[i].CATEGORY_TYPE + "</td>" +
                                        "</tr>";
                }
                TableContent += "</table>";
                $("#UpdatePanel").html(TableContent);
            },
            error: $("#UpdatePanel").html("Error")
        });
    }
```

C# code looks like this:

```
    [WebMethod]

    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public static List<Book> getBooks()
    {
        List<Book> allBooks = new List<Book>();
        using (LibraryEntities le = new LibraryEntities())
        {
            allBooks = le.Books.ToList();
        }

        return allBooks;



    }
```

My issue is that am always getting nothing and after i added:

```
error: $("#UpdatePanel").html("Error")
```

Am only getting "Error" in UpdatePanel element, i am an AJAX Newbie, need your help guys.

Comment: After debugging with internet explorer am getting this error:     '0x800a138f - Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'd.length' is null or not an object'